# Creating an IPv6 hotspot on my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, ipv6, wifi-configuration

I need to create a hotspot on my laptop so I can test some IPv6 interactions on the app I'm developing. I used the following commands on Windows 10 to set up a hosted network:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=adhocname key=password
```

and it runs fine with IPv4, but when I disable this protocol and leave only IPv6, my mobile devices fail at obtaining IP address. Any ideas on how to proceed?

I'm not even sure I'm explaining my problem correctly. I need to set up an IPv6 network that connects to the Internet so that I can test my app.

Comment: Can't you test using the IPv6 loopback protocol, `::1` ?

Comment: if only I knew what a IPv6 loopback protocol is .Sorry but i'm just a humble game developer with no idea on network stuff. Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Presumably he wants to test network interaction like discovery and whatnot, so loopback isn’t sufficient. Well, it really never is. That being said, link-local addresses (always available) should be enough. // Just noticed you want Internet connectivity: Do you even have IPv6 Internet?

Comment: ipconfig shows me that I have both a IPv4 and a IPv6 address and also a Link-local IPv6 Address. So i think I do have IPv6 internet ?

Comment: Check on [ip6.me](http://ip6.me/).

Comment: It says I'm connected with IPV4. The ipv6 page could not be reached.

Comment: Then your IPv6 address is most likely a [unique local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address). Does it start with fd00? // Either way, that means you’ll need to use a tunnel broker. I’m not sure Windows is up to the job, I’ll look into it later.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 DHCP server is specifically designed only for internet sharing, and is thus only supporting ipv4 and no configuration and no logging to reduce footprint and scope for issues.

Hence no ipv6 and after 3 years, not going to happen and not needed by end users. You will need to add a DHCP server and bridge networks to get ipv6 addresses assigned from the hotspot. 3rd party DHCP servers exist to this end. It's beyond my experience to provide more pointers, other than to suggest future readers of this question look to using a lightweight unix type host to perform the function. (Raspberry Pi) Which then requires much less debugging around the intricacies of tunneling/translation and address assignment internals of ipv6. Sorry, it's not the answer I was looking for either. Will, elaborate if I can later.

Comment: Also, be aware, that such a hotspot is not going to emulate a mobile network if it is connecting to an ipv4 only or a mixed network anyway, since it's going to tunnel (translate) at that point.